# "Nur das stelle er sich nicht etwa vor, als sei gemeint"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

German philosophical text ca. 1860 - after a long thought passage, the paragraph is concluded with two sentences directed to the reader:

> "Wir fühlen, daß dieß leicht als eine leere Formel erscheinen kann, und müssen es dem Leser überlassen, ob er Etwas dabei denken will. **Nur das stelle er sich nicht etwa vor, als sei gemeint**." [No words omitted in the citation!]

Should the last sentence be interpreted/translated as follows?:

**But he [the reader] should not imagine that he understands the meaning [i.e. what the author really meant]**

Comment: According to Google Books, the sentence doesn't end with *gemeint*; it looks like a subject clause follows.

Comment: The sentence is partial. If you're not sure about things like that, you should mention the source.

Comment: Please quote a longer piece of text, not only the sentence in question. Context is crucial.

Comment: I don't see any reason to not give proper citation for the quoted text.

Answer (score 1):

I found the text and a longer version. Looks like the sentence does not end:
[image: Original]

[image]

https://opacplus.bsb-muenchen.de/title/6339428
Page 42 (50 in the Navigation)

Comment: It's nice that you found the source. I think, you should try to answer the actual question. So doing OP's work wouldn't be wasted energy. Because - and I'm sorry to say that - right now this is not really an answer.

Comment: I am not allowed to comment yet, so thats the only way to post this. Yes, this is the OPs duty, but as i was curious and wanted to see if i could find it myself, i wanted to post the results if anyone is also curious, as the OP is not providing any more details.

Comment: Is there a reason, why the "Der" after "...gemeint," starts with a uppercase letter? This could be misunderstanding as sign for the end of the before sentence.